# Creating a dynamic (video) Overlay on Google Maps on Android 2.1

Tags: android, video, google-maps, mjpeg, overlays

I'm trying to create a map overlay for displaying a video stream (MJPEG) on top of a Mapview.

Currently I've a standalone activity that creates a data thread for fetching MJPEG video frames. I'm using a handler to send a frame (as a Bitmap) from the data thread to the main activity which then updates the UI.

I'm not sure how to implement "refresh" for updating my "overlayed" video stream.

EDIT: What I mean by "refresh" is - how can I update the video portion (not the mapview)  of my UI whenever I get a new video frame. I plan to paint the video frame (bitmap) in the "draw method" of my implementation of the Overlay subclass. But the "draw" method is not invoked by me directly.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "implement 'refresh' for updating my 'overlayed' video stream". You may wish to edit your issue to explain what you mean.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please let me now if it's clear now. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply looking to trigger a refresh, you probably just want to call `invalidate` or `postInvalidate` on the overlay, perhaps with a dirty rectangle corresponding to the overlay's current position on the map. Once invalidated, your `draw` method will be called.